# OpenVZ Web Panel Daily Backup

Tags: web, backup, panel, openvz

I am using OpenVZ Web Panel to manage my virtual machines.  For some reason,  OVZ Web Panel's "Daily Backup" option will only store a daily backup of each virtual machine. I have configured the Backups to keep to more than 1 under the User's Profile settings - setting it to values higher than 1 and "unlimited" - but the setting is ignored,  and only 1 backup copy is rotated every morning. I need at 7 daily snapshot backups for each virtual machine.

Anyone know how to let it store more backup copies?  I have searched forums, but nobody else seem to have this issue. The documentation is also not clear about this.  I have changed the owner of the virtual machine, restarted OWP - but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest and lazy-est way to do this, IMHO, is to write a script and then a cron job to run that script.

e.g.

```
cd /path/to/files
mv filename filename`date +%y%m%d` 
find /path/to/files* -mtime +5 -exec rm {} \;
```

in some script file, where filename is the name of that one file being generated then add an entry into e.g. /etc/crontab

the find that executes the rm will delete files over 5 days old.  then you get 5 days worth of backups.

probably a lot easier then requesting a feature from the devs of the program, trying to modify it yourself, etc.  (unless there is some already developed feature...)